# An alternate analysis to the (worst-case) run time of the euclidean algorithm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, computer-science, alternative-proof

I was trying to figure out the running time of the euclidean algorithm. The analysis that I found on Wikipedia and CLRS both analyze the run time of the euclidean algorithm using the Fibonacci recurrence (which I feel is rather unintuitive, so I was looking for something different). However, I remember reading a different analysis and that one can argue that it does at most $2n$ operations where $n = O(\log{b})$ (i.e. the number of bits). I remember that the argument went something like this: "In the worst case, Euclid's algorithm takes two steps to divide one of its inputs in half." However, I was having problems re-producing this argument.

So far this is what I have.

let $a_t$ and $b_t$ be the input to our gcd(a,b) program at iteration t (i.e. $\gcd(a_t,b_t)$. I have that after two iteration we have done:

$\gcd(a_t, \ b_t)$

$\gcd(a_{t+1}, \ b_{t+1}) = \gcd(b_t, \ a_t \pmod {b_t}) = \gcd(b_t, a_t - q b_t)$

$\gcd(a_{t+2}, \ b_{t+2}) = \gcd(a_t \pmod {b_t} , \ b_t \pmod {(a_t - q b_t)})$

And if one thinks in terms of bits, if $b_t$ is a power of 2, say $b_t = 2^k$, then after two steps the mod clear at least k bits from the n bit of $a_t$ to the k+1th bit of $a_t$. So for $a_{t+2}$ a bunch of higher order bits have been cleared. If we compare doing that to bit-shifting only by one bit to the right (i.e. dividing by 2), that only clears at most 1 bit, which means that after two operations, gcd at least halfs $a_t$. Which means that it clears a bit every two operations, so the run time should take worst-case 2n (if only manages to clear 1 bit every 2 iterations). However, this argument only works is $b_t$ is a power of 2 and it doesn't feel "rigorous" enough or solid enough, anyone know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It all works out if you find gcd, and solve $ax+by=1$ for coprime $a,b,$ with simple continued fractions.

Comment: If you find the Fibonacci recurrence non intuitive, think again. It is at the heart of (the worst case behaviour of) the Euclidean algorithm, and this is maybe the main reason the Fibonacci recurrence stands apart from other similar recurrences. Of course you can estimate powers of the golden ratio in terms of powers of $2$ (and vice versa), but what is really the point of doing so? The fact that you feel more _comfortable_ with $2$ as basis of exponentials should not be called that this is more intuitive, it is just your personal bias.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I don't think OP finds the rate of growth of the Fibonacci numbers non-intuitive; I take the post to mean that they find the usage of the Fibonacci recurrence in solving the Euclidean algorithm non-intuitive, which is fair - showing that the Fibonacci numbers actually provide the worst-case behavior for the Euclidean GCD algorithm is a bit tricky, and if you only care about the asymptotic  behavior then getting the $O(\log n)$ result isn't hard and doesn't require the Fibonacci sequence at all.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I find it very intuitive that the worst case behaviour of the Euclidean algorithm (using Euclidean division, not subtraction) occurs when every division has the least possible quotient, namely $1$ (except the very last one which cannot do so, and has quotient$~2$). This is not of course the same as proving this fact. Then it is quite immediate by induction that this case exactly applies for pairs of consecutive Fibonacci numbers. The rate of growth of Fibonacci numbers also immediately follows from their recurrence relation.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, I agree that intuition is very often a matter of taste (which I never denied). I still think that this alternate analysis is quite interesting and I am still interested in knowing it. Also, thanks for the advise on the Fib sequence and the algorithm, I will definitively think more about in relation to Euclid's algorithm. Understanding both of the analysis fully I feel will be very mathematically enriching. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of looking at it: WLOG, assume that $a_0\gt b_0$; then one step of the algorithm takes $(a_0, b_0)\mapsto (a_1, b_1) = (b_0, a_0\bmod b_0)$.  Now, we can break into two cases: either $b_0\leq \frac{a_0}2$ or $b_0\gt \frac{a_0}2$.

If $b_0\leq\frac{a_0}2$, then we have by definition $a_1\leq \frac{a_0}2$, and since $b_1\leq a_1$ then $b_1\leq\frac{a_0}2$.

On the other hand, if $b_0\gt\frac{a_0}2$, we have $b_1 = a_0\bmod b_0 = a_0-b_0$ since $b_0\lt a_0 \lt 2b_0$; and because $b_0\gt \frac{a_0}2$, $b_1=a_0-b_0\lt\frac{a_0}2$.

In either case, since $a_2=b_1$ then we have that $a_2\leq\frac{a_0}2$; therefore the larger input must be divided at least by two every two steps.  This is enough to show that the algorithm takes $O(\log n)$ steps to find the GCD of two numbers $\leq n$, though of course this analysis is too coarse to give the correct leading constant.